# Set cursor position to next texbox in a series

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015, C#,

In an app that gets information from a series of textboxes with an event-handler on each textbox, how do you keep the cursor from going back to the first textbox after each textbox entry?

In other words, if my customer is someone who likes to use the keyboard to tab through the data entry fields while entering data on a web page where certain on-screen information is being updated by the event handlers on each textbox, how do I get the cursor to come back to the next textbox or other control after the one just entered?

Currently, if I make an entry in the 2nd textbox in the series, upon autopostback, the cursor goes back to the first textbox. The user must then tab two times to get to the third textbox.  After entering data there, the user must tab three times to get to the fourth textbox.

How can I get the cursor to move to the next input box without the user having to tab or use the mouse?

(My search for "set cursor position" show results for graphics applications.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do exactly as you ask is to set the focus to the subsequent control in the TextChanged event for each textbox.  Thus

```
void TextBox1_OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox2.Focus();
}

void TextBox2_OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox3.Focus();
}

//etc.
```

However this isn't at all the way I would do it.  I would turn off the autopostback and find some way to replace it with AJAX.

Comment: Thank you, John.  That's just what I was looking for.  But, I thanks for the tip about AJAX.  I have no idea what it is, but if it will help in situations like this, I will endeavor to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

**In Web Form:**

```
<form runat="server" defaultFocus="txtBox1">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBox1" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBox2" TabIndex="3"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkBox1" TabIndex="2" /><br />
        <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="true" runat="server" TabIndex="4" ID="btn1" text="submit" />
    </form>
```

Look at the **TabIndex** property. How you give the value, it will change order in that way.

---

For **ASP .Net MVC**, Follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548308/setting-tab-order-on-mvc-view-with-dropdownlistfor-editorfor) in the link. Its quite full.

---

For **Windows Form Application**
Its simplest. Select a control and go to properties window and set the **tabindex** property.

---

Here are few links which will direct you to solution. Basically you need to search with

> "set tab index in web form / win form / razor view

" (which one you are using)

**TabIndex Property:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178231.aspx

Comment: Thank you Abdur.  I will look these up.